# How to check a selected Column using if condition in mybatis?

Tags: java, sql, mybatis

Select selectedColumn

```
<if test="selectedColumn != null">Content</if>
```

from Table;

Only if u pass parameter from the request. U can use that **variable** only inside `"<if test='**variable**  != null'>"`. But i need to check the selectedColumn value inside if like CASE statement in SQL.

Comment: Try to explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: Read the manual: http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html  And you can easily apply the if tag to the select clause too.

Comment: Actually, only parameter can be used inside if test='parameter'. I want to check the selected column value like CASE statement in SQL.

Comment: What do you mean by 'check the selected column'? Are you talking about the value of the column? If this is the case this is not possible. `<if...>` in mybatis works when SQL statement is generated that is before it is executed and any values of select are available. Why SQL `CASE` statement does not work for you? What do you try to achieve?

Comment: Exactly, 'check the selected column' - Value of the column. There is no way to achieve it ? @RomanKonoval

Comment: No way. How do you expect it to work when `<if>` is executed **before** the query is executed and result is retrieved?

Comment: Thank you. I've done it with CASE itself without using <if> in mybatis.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to use the value of the column in mybatis `<if...>` because the value becomes available to mybatis after the query is executed, but `<if...>` works at the earlier stage namely when the query text is constructed to be sent to the database for execution.